# Find a value, return the cell below it (or up to 4 below it) where the first value starts with a 1

Tags: excel, import, ms-word, excel-formula, formulas

I have a word file imported in Excel. The file is in column A, up to 400-500 rows long. To illustrate as an example:

```
Type application
0 shortcut
1 Client installation (standalone)
0 Client installation with data on the network (fileshare needed)
0 Client/server (server needed)
0 Webbased without dependancies
0 Webbased with dependancies
Importancy
0 Company critical
1 Important
0 Supportive
```

And many other fields of interest. Now I have a formula that **searches** for a certain text value, for example "Product manager" and **returns** the value below it (the name). To illustrate:

```
=INDEX(A:A;MATCH("Product manager";A:A;0)+2;1)
```

Here, the +2 returns the name of the product manager.

**The problem I need YOUR help with!**

The problem is as follows. In the big block of code above you see a bit value, with the 1 corresponding with the check box clicked in the word file. Now I want to search on *Type application* and **return only** the value corresponding with the 1, so in this case *1 Client installation (standalone)*.

The above solution with INDEX and MATCH doesn't work because it only returns a certain row *below* the search query (so row +1, or row +5). I want to find the value *Type application*, serach in the 6 rows below it and return the only 1 value it will find.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following the example of my more illustrious colleagues, I have started trying to use INDEX for this sort of question, so the answer would be something like this:-

```
=INDEX(INDEX(B$1:B$10,MATCH(D2,B$1:B$10,0)):B$10,MATCH(1,INDEX(A$1:A$10,MATCH(D2,B$1:B$10,0)):A$10,0))
```

so it finds the string (e.g. charlie) in column B, and searches the rest of the range in column A for a '1'.

[image]

If all the values are in one column as in the question, the formula becomes

```
=INDEX(INDEX(A$1:A$10,MATCH(D2,A$1:A$10,0)):A$10,
MATCH("1*",INDEX(A$1:A$10,MATCH(D2,A$1:A$10,0)):A$10,0))
```

[image]

To put a limit on the range and error handling should be something like this:-

```
=IFERROR(
INDEX(INDEX(A:A,MATCH(D2,A:A,0)):
INDEX(A:A,MATCH(D2,A:A,0)+4),
MATCH("1*",INDEX(A:A,MATCH(D2,A:A,0)):
INDEX(A:A,MATCH(D2,A:A,0)+4),0)),
"No entry")
```

If you wanted to search more than one column in the same way, you could use the same sort of formula but it wouldn't be practical without using helper columns. So copy it across (say) two columns, then display the first match.

Set up the start of search in E2:-

```
=MATCH(D2,A$1:A$20,0)+1
```

End of search in F2 could just be E2+4, but you can also search up to the next 'subheading' using:-

```
=MATCH(1,INDEX((INDEX(A$1:A$20,E2):A$20>"2")+(INDEX(A$1:A$20,E2):A$20=""),),0)+E2-2
```

The search for a cell starting with "1" in G2:-

```
=IFERROR(MATCH("1*",INDEX(A$1:A$20,$E2):INDEX(A$1:A$20,$F2),0),"")
```

and pull across into H2 and I2.

Get the first of the three matches in J2:-

```
=MIN(G2:I2)
```

And find which columns it applies to in K2:-

```
=IF(J2=0,"",MATCH(J2,G2:I2,0))
```

Finally get the matching cell using the row and column in J2 and K2:-

```
=IF(K2="","No entry",INDEX(INDEX(A$1:A$20,E2):C$20,J2,K2))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for your input and hard work for a complete stranger! I really dig this site. One last question and then I'm out. What if I want to put a search range of, for example +4 rows when it found a certain key? My scenario contains the second image. Some keys may have no 1, in this case I want it to return a certain value (for example, "no entry"). At the moment it searches till it finds a row that returns a 1, while I only want it to search in the next 3 of 4 or 5 rows.

Comment: Have added to my answer. Would be nice if it could search up to the next 'key', but don't know how to do this :-)

Comment: Thanks alot Tom Sharpe for your help so far. I have one more question I just can't figure out and I really hope you can shed some light upon this problem.

The thing: I want to search in a specific RANGE of cells and columns. For example, I search on the term "Application". Once it is found, I want to search FROM that cell (for example, A30) up to 5 rows down and 2 columns right (so from A30 to C35) for the FIRST value that returns a one. I want that first 1 to be returned with the corresponding text following it (using the 1 as a wildcard).... I hope you can help me!

Comment: That would be really tough. Because MATCH can only deal with one column, you'd probably need a different approach using an array formula or VBA. Will come back to you if I think of anything.

Comment: Actually it is OK to do it but will need some helper columns because too much to do with one formula. Will add to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Say we have data like:

[image]

and we want to:

1. find *Puck*
2. return the first value starting with *"1"* below *Puck*

Using *Match()* with a wildcard can locate the row with *Puck*.  So in **C5**, we enter:

```
=MATCH("*Puck",A1:A9999,0)
```

then we use *Match()* again to find the row below that that starts with *"1"*.  So in **C6** we enter::

```
=INDEX(A1:A9999,MATCH("1*",INDIRECT("A" & C5 & ":A9999"),0)+C5-1)
```

[image]

Naturally this 2-cell approach can always be combined into one cell.

Comment: Thanks alot Gary for your input, it is much appreciated! I choose the solution provided by Tom Sharpe, but I still have an unsolved solution. It's posted under his solution, do you maybe have an idea on how to do this?